# wordpress homepage both http and https set default as https

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache

Is there a way to allow access to http:// and https:// on the HOMEPAGE of wordpress site? the default should be https://. So when I type example.com it should redirect to https://example.com but when I enter http://example.com it should not redirect to any link and just use the http version. All links to the images inside the pages should be https://

I have a UC SSL certificate from godaddy

Comment: Is there a particular technical reason why you want to have both http and https with https being default? If you already have the option to go with SSL, there exists no technical reason why it shouldn't be the only option really - you get the benefits of clients that can use `http2` protocol, your page is ranked higher and, of course, it's better in terms of preventing eavesdropping. I'm asking because I don't know how to make the 443 port default with port 80 being 2nd option, but if you can have SSL on your site - it *should* be the **only** option.

Comment: It can be done 443 port default and port 80 as an option but in wordpress it's difficult. The reason I want this because I need to add my website to directory listing for backlinks and they don't accept SSL not having the primary domain name as my domain name. Our SSL is issued to a different domain name. issued to mail.example.com and my client doesn't want it changed

Comment: You know that you can get free SSL certificates from [letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)? If you are the expert, and client won't budge, you shouldn't go head over heels to provide a solution for someone inflexible. Anyway, I'm not helping out here since I'm not the Apache guy (and I think this is wrong order of doing things) so I'll leave you with an upvote and hopefully someone more knowledgeable will help you out. Good luck!

Comment: yes I realize that. I'm just trying to find out if there's another way though. thank you. thanks for giving me information about letsencrypt will be trying it soon

Comment: While there **may be** a way to do this, it's a nuisance to set up and make work, and I suspect would have **negative consequences** from Google and potentially other search engines.

Comment: google have the primary link feature right? which can point http to https?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use just https without any SSL then browsers may often identify you as malware it is recomended not to use this work, but if you are insisting on your decision, so you can edit your .htaccess file and tell which urls you want to be https and which you dont want.and you should change your port thats not easy work...
Again i suggest you not to use this work, cause useing https and http without any ssl is not useful...
Good luck

Comment: I have SSL certificate installed on the server. I just want it optional but set it as a default